# Na hora de cadastrar o formulário php com uma imagem ele só envia a imagem pra pasta mas não cadastra os dados no banco

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, imagem

Esse é meu formulário

```
<form method="post" id="show" action="inserir/inserir_show.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <h4>Nome do show</h4>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" id="inputEmail" required="">
                    </div>
                    <h4>Diretor do show</h4>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="diretor" id="inputEmail" required="">
                    </div>
                    <h4>Foto do show</h4>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" id="inputEmail" required="">
                    </div>
                    <h4>Frase</h4><!--frase-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frase" id="inputEmail" required="">
                    </div>
                    <h4>Descrição</h4><!--descrição-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="descricao" id="inputEmail" required="">
                    </div>
                    <h4>Data do show</h4>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="data" id="inputEmail" required="">



                    </div>
                    <h4>Local do show</h4>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="local" id="inputEmail" required="">
                    </div>
                    <h4>Categoria do show</h4>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="categoria" id="inputEmail" required="">
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>

                </form>
```

E o inserir no banco

```
<?php

include "conecta.php";

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$diretor = $_POST['diretor'];
$data = $_POST['data'];
$descricao = $_POST['descricao'];
$frase = $_POST['frase'];
$local = $_POST['local'];
$categoria = $_POST['categoria'];
$foto = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$target = "img/" .basename($_FILES['image']['name']);



    $cadastro_show = "INSERT INTO show(nomeShow, diretorShow, dataShow, descricaoShow, fraseShow, localShow, categoriaShow, fotoShow) VALUES ('$nome', '$diretor', '$data', '$descricao', '$frase', $local', '$categoria', '$foto')";

    mysqli_set_charset($link, x'utf8');

    mysqli_query($link, $cadastro_show);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
     echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Cadastrado com sucesso :)');window.location.href='../shows.php';</script>";
}else{
     echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Houve um Erro ao cadastrar o show');window.location.href='../shows.php';</script>";
}


mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

A imagem que eu seleciono no form envia para a pasta "img/" e aparece a mensagem que cadastrou mas não envia nenhum dado para o banco, alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Victória para poder responder com mais certeza, precisaria vez como esta sendo feita a conexão de banco de dados. Passa o código do conecta.php Aparentemente tudo esta em ordem no código postado, sendo que eu incluiria um controle de transação, so para ter certeza que o upload e o insert de dados aconteceriam.

Comment: esse aqui é o conecta.php



<?php

$servidor='localhost';
$usuario ='root';
$senha ='';
$banco ='bancoppi';

$link = mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$senha,$banco) or die;

?>